# How to select in table and results sorted by another table

Tags: mysql

Hi I was trying to create mysql statement that fit to my requirement.
2 tables as below

postTable

```
post_id | from_id
100     | 1
100     | 2
100     | 3
100     | 4
100     | 5
```

loveTable

```
post    | uid
1       | 1
100     | 3
100     | 4
100     | 5
5       | 6
```

I want to `select from_id from postTable where post_id=100 order by` //uid that have post =100 in loveTable firstly.

Expecting result

```
from_id
 3
 4
 5
 1
 2
```

Can you please advise me what is the right select statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select p.from_id 
from postTable p left join lovetable o on p.from_id=o.uid
and o.post=100 
where p.post_id=100
order by o.uid is not null desc,p.from_id
```

[SQL FIDDLE HERE.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2596/12)

Comment: Thanks Sel that the value answer for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT from_id FROM postTable pt
LEFT JOIN loveTable lt
ON pt.from_id = lt.uid
WHERE pt.post_id  = 100
ORDER BY lt.post desc
```

## [*See this SQLFiddle*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b89f/13)

Comment: Thanks to hims056 that's nice.