# Mysql call result order by other table

Tags: mysql

Please allow me to as a stupid question again.
It is really hard for me to call query mysql from both tables.

post_table

```
    PostID | UID_frm

    10     | 1
    10     | 2
    10     | 3
    10     | 4
    10     | 5
```

user_table

```
    Name   | FID

    tom    | 2
    tom    | 3
    henry  | 4
```

I want to have this below as result.

```
UID_frm
2
3
1
4
5
```

It is the result from column UID_frm but priority order by user_table.FID.
Please advise I want to call like this:(but doesn't work)

```
select UID_frm 
from post_table 
where PostID='10'  
order by (select FID 
            from user_table 
           where Name='tom')
```

Comment: Please clarify: You want to list all posts of tom first, ordered by FID, then all the others ordered by - what?

Comment: Does post_table.UID_frm referring from user_table.FID ? What is relation between tables post_table and user_table?

Comment: Hi Alex Monthy, I don't want to order FID, then it should easier.

Comment: Didn't you ask almost the same question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982067/how-to-select-in-table-and-results-sorted-by-another-table

Comment: Hi Somnath Muluk, There are independence.

Comment: Hi Barmar, It is my another difficulty for me, please don't vote me down.

Comment: Why doesn't the answer from your other thread work for this problem?

Comment: Hi Barmar, I have just changed my database structure, so my previous one was not applicable for me, please understand my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT UID_frm
FROM post_table a
     LEFT JOIN user_table b
        ON a.UID_frm = b.FID
WHERE PostID = '10'
ORDER BY (IF(b.Name = 'tom', b.FID, NULL)) ASC, a.UID_frm ASC
```

Comment: Hi Omesh, this one working for me. I just change from ASC to DESC. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select PT.UID_frm 
    from post_table as PT,user_table as UT
    where UT.FID=PT.UID_frm and PT.PostID='10'
    order by UT.name ASC/DESC
```